# ASP.NET Identity e Web API - Problema para registrar novo usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um projeto Web API e estou usando o Identity para gerenciar contas de usuários, no meu controller está assim:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegisterDto model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    try
    {
        var registerDomain = Mapper.Map<RegisterDto, Customer>(model);
        registerDomain.UserName = registerDomain.Email;
        _customerService.Insert(registerDomain);
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(registerDomain, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(registerDomain.Id); 
        var callbackUrl = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Account", action = "ConfirmEmail", userId = registerDomain.Id, code = code });
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(registerDomain.Id, "Confirmação de conta", "Porfavor confirme a sua conta clicando nesse link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Porém o resultado de `UserManager.CreateAsync` está dando o seguinte erro: `Name cannot be null or empty`.

`Name` é uma propriedade de `Customer` (`Customer` herda de `IdentityUser`) e a *string* está sendo passado corretamente, inclusive no `RegisterDto` a propriedade é required, se fosse nula ou ou vazia não passava na verificação do `ModelState`.

Já pesquisei na net e tem gente com o mesmo problema, porém as soluções não estão funcionando, alguém pode dar uma dica?

O código da `RegisterDto`

```
public class RegisterDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Cpf { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A senha e a confirmação da senha não são iguais.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, acredito que não tem haver diretamente com a propriedade Name de Customer, digo isso porque nas respostas que encontrei na net a classe customizada de IdentityUser não tinha nenhuma propriedade chamada Name, realmente estou perdido aqui. :(

Comment: Pode por favor editar sua pergunta e colocar o código de `RegisterDto`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez adicionei o código da `RegisterDto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema não é muito fácil de resolver porque a mensagem de erro não ajuda muito. Na verdade a origem do problema é aqui:

```
registerDomain.UserName = registerDomain.Email;
```

Por padrão, o validador da entidade de usuário não aceita caracteres como o `@` e o `.` em `UserName`. Por isso é necessário antes ajustar o validador pra aceitar caracteres especiais para o nome do usuário:

```
UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<TUser>(UserManager) { 
                                  AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false }
```

Comment: Já tinha feito essa configuração, e também já tinha testado colocar o login sem caracteres especiais, o erro persiste.

Comment: @rhgm Bom, eu não usaria o Automapper se fosse você. Mesmo que ele gere um objeto correto, eu faria o processo manual antes pra garantir que está funcionando.

Comment: Testei sem usar o Automapper, alterei para receber a classe `Customer` assim não preciso fazer o mapeamento. Agora deu uma exception: The entity type Customer is not part of the model for the current context, já é uma msg melhor... :)
Vou testar mais pra saber onde está o problema.

Comment: Ok, me deixe informado. Atualizo a resposta no decorrer.

Comment: realmente o autoMapper não estava mapeando corretamente, a propriedade Email ficava nula no mapeamento, por isso dava a menssagem `Name cannot be null or empty` e descobri que essa propriedade Name se refere ao UserName do `IdentityUser`.
Só hoje tive tempo pra analisar a exception. Por conta desse erro percebi que a minha classe `Customer` (que herda de `IdentityUser`) quando é criado a tabela no banco só tem as propriedades do `IdentityUser`, as propriedades customizadas que fiz não aparecem, por isso está dando a exception.

Comment: @rhgm Em resumo, a resposta serve? Ou preciso modificá-la?

Comment: Serve sim, agora o problema é outro, então é outra pergunta. Obrigado!